# jinja2 variables naming - Are variables naming restrictions the same as for Python variables?

Tags: python, jinja2

I did't find it written explicitly in the docs.

Are the naming rules the same as with Python variables?

(eg: `{{ a_variable'like_that' }}` doesn't work for example)

Comment: Why do you want to know? If it doesn't work, use another name.

Comment: @dAnjou pretty surprising reaction! Feels misplaced...

I need to build a jinja template from text that already has its own (decoupled) tagging syntax, which is not having such limitation on variables names (placeholders). Thus, I need to know that to build a robust translator.

I didn't find a jinja forum / mailing list, so I told myself I would just post my question on SO. I will let other users judge if it's worthwhile

Comment: It's not inappropriate. Many beginner programmers want to do weird stuff. So I better ask *why* they want to do it so that I can give better support. Back to your question: to be safe, make sure those names are [`\w+`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes). And you didn't find what? http://jinja.pocoo.org/community/

Comment: Ok fine. And for sure I didn't look correctly for the jinja community page! Must have had my mind somewhere else. But "whatever", I think this question has its place on SO as well, deserves to be answered and finally most of all to be written in the doc.

Comment: Report a bug: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/issues/new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete and updated answer can be found at the following link:

https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#notes-on-identifiers

> Jinja uses Python naming rules. Valid identifiers can be any
> combination of characters accepted by Python.
>
> Filters and tests are looked up in separate namespaces and have
> slightly modified identifier syntax. Filters and tests may contain
> dots to group filters and tests by topic. For example it’s perfectly
> valid to add a function into the filter dict and call it to.str. The
> regular expression for filter and test identifiers is
> [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(.[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)*.

Answer (score 2):

Jinja's naming convention generally matches your python interpreter's identifiers. So it also depends on your Python version ([2.x](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers): like `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*`)

(source: #pocoo on irc.freenode.net)

Comment: Source would be nice.

Comment: That’s a shame to have to rename variables just to comply with Python :(