# Airflow how to read JSON Input Params which includes '-' in the middle of param using Jinja

Tags: jinja2, airflow, airflow-2.x

I’m running my DAG with configuration JSON, which includes parameters which includes `-`, e.g. `market-name`
When I’m trying to read it using the following Jinja template:

```
path_prefix = f"market={{{{ params.market-name }}}}/configuration"
```

I’m getting the following error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'market'
```

It seems to me that Jinja doesn’t identify the full param name market-name but get the first part before the `-` which is market .

My questions:

1. Does Jinja supports having `-` in the middle of a param (e.g. `market-name`) or should I avoid it from the beginning  and use `market_name` instead?
2. If Jinja doesn’t support having a `-` in the middle of a param

- Should I escape the `market-name` ?
- How should I escape it?

3. Should I use `{{ params.market-name }}` instead of `{{{{ params.market-name }}}}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Airflow bug. I reported it in this [issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/8688) and this is a problem coming from Jinja/Python.

I could have not find any official documentation in Jinja that explains it but several reports mention that Jinja uses python interpreter's identifiers (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687534/jinja2-variables-naming-are-variables-naming-restrictions-the-same-as-for-pyth) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652373/jinja2-in-variable-bug)). It might be best to report this issue to Jinja add documentation about it.

You can just avoid using `-`.